# Localized DisplayName attribute in Orchard CMS

Tags: localization, data-annotations, orchardcms

I have seen this question in other forms (mainly related to validation), but couldnt understand the answers.

I have the following:

```
    [Required, DisplayName("First Name")]
    public virtual string GivenName { get; set; }
```

I would like to have the DisplayName localized. I have made an attemt by creating a RequiredAttribute Extension as one of the others did:

```
public class RequiredFieldAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
    {
        public RequiredFieldAttribute()
        {
            T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        }

        public Localizer T { get; set; }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
            var field = T(name).Text;
            return T("Please fill in {0}.", field).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

The error message returned keeps giving back the English name. But I am sure there is a translation, because when I use the following in a view, I get the localized name:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => register.GivenName, T("First Name"))
```

Also the message itself (please fill in...) is localized. Except the field name isn't. How come the string for fieldname is localized when asking for it in the view, but not when using it in the extension.

When looking at discussion on codeplex, I saw that some changeset has fixed an issue about localized data annotations in namespace `Orchard.MVC.DataAnnotations`. But I can't find any example in the existing modules on how to use those.

Answer (score 2):

This question is probably outdated but i was asking myself the same thing in Orchard CMS 1.8.1. So here is how i have done it.

Lets say you have a model that looks like

```
public class Message
{
  [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a date."]
  public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

and you want to have a german translation for the required validation message then you create a `App_Data\Localization\de-DE\orchard.module.po` file in your module and put the following paragraph in it

```
msgctxt "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute"
msgid "Please select a date."
msgstr "Bitte wählen Sie ein Datum."
```

You can even skip the msgctxt line (that's the scope of the translation) as its working without it also. A description of the .po file format can be found at http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html.

If the translations are not working then the following methods are a good debug entry point:

```
Orchard/Localization/Text.cs
public LocalizedString Get(string textHint, params object[] args) ...

Orchard/Localization/Services/DefaultLocalizedStringManager.cs
public string GetLocalizedString() ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running across this issue as well. I wonder if you got it worked out.

You mention you cannot find the Orchard.MVC.DataAnnotations examples. They are located at (if you are working with the Orchard source (as of 1.6)) `~/Orchard.Framework/Mvc/DataAnnotations`.

And this is what `LocalizedRequiredAttribute.cs` looks like:

```
namespace Orchard.Mvc.DataAnnotations {
public class LocalizedRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute {
    public LocalizedRequiredAttribute(RequiredAttribute attribute, Localizer t) {
        AllowEmptyStrings = attribute.AllowEmptyStrings;

        if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.ErrorMessage) )
            ErrorMessage = attribute.ErrorMessage;

        T = t;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage)
            ? T("The {0} field is required.", name).Text
            : T(ErrorMessage, name).Text;
    }
}
```

<strike>So you have to decorate with `[LocalizedRequiredAttribute]`.</strike> Sorry, my understanding now is that you continue, in this example, to use [Required] as before, and Orchard takes care of changing it for you. You do, however, have to manually create your `.po` files because the TranslationManager doesn't pick these up.

I myself am having trouble trying to localize the `[Display(Name="")]` attribute. Part of my confusing is in `System.ComponentModel` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` because they both have similar attributes (`DisplayNameAttribute` for the former, and `DisplayAttibute` for the latter).

Answer (score 0):

you can use normal validation same normal mvc project in orchard project
You just have to add these settings to the webconfig :

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

end